# Cannot understand reason for comparison between float and object instantiation

Tags: c++, valgrind, tesseract

I cannot understand the following code from Tesseract's control.cpp:

```
(stats_.doc_outline_errs / static_cast<float>(page_res->char_count) <=
     quality_outline_pc)
```

`stats_.doc_outline_errs` is a `short`, `page_res->char_count` is an `int` but `quality_outline_pc` is:

```
double_VAR_H(quality_outline_pc, 1.0,
               "good_quality_doc lte outline error limit");
```

and `double_VAR_H` is:

```
#define double_VAR_H(name,val,comment)\
  tesseract::DoubleParam     name
```

It seems we are comparing a `short` divided by an `int` casted to `float` with a variable declaration, namely `tesseract::DoubleParam quality_outline_pc`?

Is it some C++ specific feature?

The reason I'm looking into this is that I get an error from Valgrind at this line:

```
==29454== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29454==    at 0x5AB9E76: tesseract::Tesseract::rejection_passes(PAGE_RES*, ETEXT_DESC*, TBOX const*, char const*) (control.cpp:665)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "comparing ... with a variable declaration?" It looks like to me like it's comparing with `quality_outline_pc` which is a [`tesseract::DoubleParam`](http://zdenop.github.io/tesseract-doc/classtesseract_1_1_double_param.html) which can be converted to `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems we are comparing a short divided by an int casted to float with a variable declaration, namely `tesseract::DoubleParam quality_outline_pc`?

I don't know what you mean by "comparing with a variable declaration". You're comparing the value of a calculation with the value of a variable. The [`DoubleParam`](http://zdenop.github.io/tesseract-doc/classtesseract_1_1_double_param.html) type is convertible to `double`, using its conversion operator `operator double()`. The result of the division will be converted from `float` to `double` to match, and those two values will be compared.

> Is it some C++ specific feature?

I've no idea what you mean by that either. All of these operations (type conversions, division and comparison) are part of the C++ language.

> The reason I'm looking into this is that I get an error from Valgrind

It means that one of those variables hasn't been initialised.

Comment: Isn't `tesseract::DoubleParam quality_outline_pc` a variable declaration (object instantiation which returns the object)? It is C++-specific since it is does not exist in C, contrarily to the `if`, the division, the comparison, etc. Thanks, I was looking but couldn't figure what the `operator double` was there for.

Comment: @JoãoM.S.Silva: Yes, that's a variable declaration. It declares a variable called `quality_outline_pc`, whose value is used by the comparison expression. I've no idea what you mean by "object instantiation which returns the object", that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I've learned / was introduced to OO programming with Java, and if I remember correctly, declaring a variable from a class is instantiating an object from that class? But maybe this nomenclature does not apply to C++.

Comment: @JoãoM.S.Silva: Yes, the variable declaration instantiates the class to give an object. The comparison is with that object's value. You should ignore whatever you know about Java, since C++ has quite a different object model.